# AngularJS: After data entry, views update on laptop/desktop but not mobile device

Tags: ios, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I've been working on this problem off and on for a week and searching for answers in the Angular docs and on StackOverflow but I cannot find a solution. As the question indicates, the model updates in all devices, but the corresponding views are not updating on mobile phones. I have used dev tools on my iphone and can see in the console that the relevant information is being passed to the database and stored, but then the corresponding view does not appear as it does on my laptop. I have checked on other mobile devicies, other laptops, and a variety of browsers and I believe the problem is isolated to mobile. I'm using Node.js/sails.js as my server and MongoDB as my database.

To provide some more specific context:my app uses modals forms that takes user input. When the form is submitted, an AJAX call is made, which then creates media - maps, timelines, comments. The view is refreshed in the callback function from the original $modal.open function.

Below are some code snippets. This first function below opens the modal - note the callback that queries the database and provides new data to update the view:

```
  $scope.newMap = function() {
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl:'/views/maps/addMapModal.html',
        controller: 'AddMapModalCtrl'
      }).result.then(function(){
        Project.get({id: $routeParams.id}, function(data) {
        console.log(data.maps[0].id)
        $scope.project = data

      });
    });
  }
```

This second function is the modal controller and creates the new map instance in my database:

```
    $scope.addMap = function() {
      var zoom
      var theme
      if($scope.zoom) {
       if ($scope.zoom === "Neighborhood") {
        zoom = 14
       } else if ($scope.zoom === "City") {
        zoom = 10
       } else if ($scope.zoom === "Region") {
        zoom = 8
       } else if ($scope.zoom === "Country") {
        zoom = 5
       } else if ($scope.zoom === "Continent") {
        zoom = 4
       } else if ($scope.zoom === "World") {
        zoom = 2
       } else {
        alert("Please choose either Neighborhood, City, Region, Country, Continent or World")
       }
     }
     if($scope.theme) {
      if ($scope.theme === "18th Century") {
          theme = tilesDict.mapbox_pirates
       }
       else if ($scope.theme === "Grayscale") {
          theme = tilesDict.mapbox_light
       }
       else if ($scope.theme === "Physical Features") {
          theme = tilesDict.mapbox_outdoors
       }
       else {
         theme = tilesDict.openstreetmap
       }
     }
      var map = new AddMap()
      map.name = $scope.name;
      map.description = $scope.description
      map.country = $scope.country;
      map.city = $scope.city;
      map.zoom = zoom;
      map.theme = theme;
      map.$save({projectId: $scope.project.id}, function(data) {
        console.log('map created')
        console.log(data)
        $scope.project = data;
        $modalInstance.close();
      })
    }
```

As noted, I know the database instance is being created from using dev tools on my iPhone, but also because the new map info shows up on my laptop once it has been entered on my phone. I've tried various fixes - for example, including ngTouch, wrapping the $modal.open callback in a $watch and $scope.$apply function - but nothing has worked. I was hoping someone might be able to provide me some additional insight. Thanks!